# TSQL for XML Path Grouping

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, nested, sqlxml

I'm having issues trying to group / nest my results as shown below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Required XML output**

```
<WorkflowLog>
  <Process id="Type1">
    <ProcessInstance id="M11111">
      <AuditTrailEntry>
        <Data>
          <Attribute name="TypeSubCause">EMB</Attribute>
        </Data>
        <WorkflowModelElement>C_Created</WorkflowModelElement>
        <EventType>Start</EventType>
        <TimeStamp>2013-10-02T10:00:33</TimeStamp>
        <Originator>C_Team</Originator>
      </AuditTrailEntry>
      <AuditTrailEntry>
        <Data>
          <Attribute name="TypeSubCause">EMB</Attribute>
        </Data>
        <WorkflowModelElement>ITPSPotential</WorkflowModelElement>
        <EventType>Start</EventType>
        <TimeStamp>2013-10-03T09:15:32+10.00</TimeStamp>
        <Originator>R_Team</Originator>
      </AuditTrailEntry>
    </ProcessInstance>
  </Process>
</WorkflowLog>
```

**Actual XML output from my SQL**
The Process Id and ProcessInstance ID are showing multiple times for the same Id's

```
<WorkflowLog>
  <Process id="Type1">
    <ProcessInstance id="M11111">
      <AuditTrailEntry>
        <Data>
          <Attribute name="TypeSubCause">EMBt</Attribute>
        </Data>
        <WorkflowModelElement>c_Created</WorkflowModelElement>
        <EventType>Start</EventType>
        <TimeStamp>2013-10-02T10:00:33+10.00</TimeStamp>
        <Originator>C_Team</Originator>
      </AuditTrailEntry>
    </ProcessInstance>
  </Process>
  <Process id="Type1">
    <ProcessInstance id="M11111">
      <AuditTrailEntry>
        <Data>
          <Attribute name="TypeSubCause">EMB</Attribute>
        </Data>
        <WorkflowModelElement>ITPSPotential</WorkflowModelElement>
        <EventType>Start</EventType>
        <TimeStamp>2013-10-03T09:15:32+10.00</TimeStamp>
        <Originator>R_Team</Originator>
      </AuditTrailEntry>
    </ProcessInstance>
  </Process>
</WorkflowLog>
```

**The SQL generating this is**

```
SELECT  '@id' = m1.TypeCause ,
        ( SELECT    '@id' = m2.MTypeNumber ,
                    ( SELECT    'TypeSubCause' AS [Data/Attribute/@name] ,
                                m3.[TypeSubCause] AS [Data/Attribute/*] ,
                                m3.[Subject] AS [WorkflowModelElement] ,
                                'Start' AS [EventType] ,
                                m3.[date] AS [TimeStamp] ,
                                m3.[AssignedGroup] AS [Originator]
                      FROM      #CombinedDataSets M3
                      WHERE     m3.TypeCause = 'C_Only'
                                AND m2.MTypeNumber = m3.MTypeNumber
                                AND m2.Subject = m3.Subject
                                AND m2.date = m3.date
                    FOR
                      XML PATH('AuditTrailEntry') ,
                          TYPE
                    )
          FROM      #CombinedDataSets m2
          WHERE     m2.TypeCause = 'C_Only'
                    AND m1.MTypeNumber = m2.MTypeNumber
                    AND m1.Subject = m2.Subject
                    AND m1.date = m2.date
        FOR
          XML PATH('ProcessInstance') ,
              TYPE
        )
FROM    #CombinedDataSets m1
WHERE   m1.TypeCause = 'C_Only'
ORDER BY m1.TypeCause ,
        m1.MTypeNumber ,
        m1.date
FOR     XML PATH('Process') ,
            ROOT('WorkflowLog')
```

Added - Example Data

```
CREATE TABLE #CombinedDataSets
    (
      [MTypeNumber] VARCHAR(10) ,
      subject VARCHAR(25) ,
      [Date] DATETIME ,
      [AssignedGroup] VARCHAR(25) ,
      [TypeCause] VARCHAR(25) ,
      [TypeSubCause] VARCHAR(25)
    )

INSERT  INTO #CombinedDataSets
        ( [MTypeNumber] ,
          [subject] ,
          [Date] ,
          [AssignedGroup] ,
          [TypeCause] ,
          [TypeSubCause] 
        )
        SELECT  'M11111' ,
                'C_Created' ,
                '2013-10-02 10:00:33' ,
                'CA' ,
                'C_Only' ,
                'EMB'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'M11111' ,
                'ITPSPotential' ,
                '2013-10-03 09:15:32' ,
                'ALLPIC' ,
                'C_Only' ,
                'EMB'

SELECT  *
FROM    #CombinedDataSets

MTypeNumber subject Date    AssignedGroup   TypeCause   TypeSubCause
M11111  C_Created   2013-10-02 10:00:33.000 CA  C_Only  EMB
M11111  ITPSPotential   2013-10-03 09:15:32.000 ALLPIC  C_Only  EMB
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `group by` into your query:

```
select
    m1.TypeCause as [@id1],
    (
        select
            m2.MTypeNumber as [@id],
            (
                select 
                    'TypeSubCause' as [Data/Attribute/@name],
                    m3.[TypeSubCause] as [Data/Attribute],
                    m3.[Subject] as [WorkflowModelElement],
                   'Start' as [EventType],
                    m3.[date] as [TimeStamp],
                    m3.[AssignedGroup] as [Originator],
                from dbo.CombineDataSets as m3
                where
                    m3.LossCause = 'C_Only' and
                    m3.MTypeNumber = m2.MTypeNumber
                    m3.Subject = m2.Subject and
                    m3.date = m2.date
                for xml path('AuditTrailEntry'), type
            )
        from dbo.CombineDataSets as m2
        where
            m2.TypeCause = 'Contents Only' and
            m2.MTypeNumber = m1.MTypeNumber
            m2.Subject = m1.Subject
            m2.date = m1.date
        for xml path('ProcessInstance'), type
    )
from dbo.CombineDataSets as m1
where m1.TypeCause='C_Only'
group by m1.TypeCause, m1.date, m1.MTypeNumber, m1.Subject
order by m1.TypeCause
for xml path('Process'), root('WorkflowLog')
```

Comment: Still returns the same results. I've tried using group by though out the query but not change to the xml results

Comment: It'd be easier if you add example input table to your question

Comment: Sorry should have thought of that, I have added the sample data to end of original submission.

Answer (score 1):

Roman was correct, the issue was with my grouping but also with the where statement joins.

```
select
   m1.TypeCause as [@id1],
   (
   SELECT m2.MTypeNumber as [@id],
            (
                select 

                    'TypeSubCause' as [Data/Attribute/@name],
                    m3.[TypeSubCause] as [Data/Attribute],
                    m3.[Subject] as [WorkflowModelElement],
                   'Start' as [EventType],
                    m3.[date] as [TimeStamp],
                    m3.[AssignedGroup] as [Originator]
                from #CombinedDataSets as m3
                where
                m3.MTypeNumber=m2.MTypeNumber
                and m3.TypeCause=m2.TypeCause
               for xml path('AuditTrailAudit'),type
            )    
    from #CombinedDataSets  as m2
where
m2.TypeCause='C_Only'
group by m2.TypeCause, m2.MTypeNumber
for XML path('ProcessInstance'),type
)
from #CombinedDataSets  as m1
where
    m1.TypeCause='Contents Only'
group by 
m1.TypeCause
For XML path('Process'),Root('WorkflowLog')
```

Comment: so you can accept either one answer, so the question will be answered